# Is there any validation check for already registered email id in ruby programming

Tags: ruby

```
# load in the webdriver gem to interect with selenium
require 'selenium-webdriver'
#setup chrome plugin
driver = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path='C:\Users\vidhi\Desktop\Ruby Folder\chromedriver.exe'
#this line will start the browser
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 20)

def document_initialised(driver)
  driver.execute_script('return initialised')
end
#Navigate to URl
driver.get "http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=authentication&back=my-account#account-creation"
#Maximize the window
driver.manage.window.maximize
sleep 6
driver.action.key_down(:enter).perform
sleep 5

driver.find_element(:id,"email_create").send_keys "demouser099@gmail.com"
sleep 5
driver.action.key_down(:enter).perform
driver.find_element(:id,"SubmitCreate").click
sleep 2
driver.action.key_down(:enter).perform

#### Check that the radio button exists
puts "Test Passed: Radio button found" if wait.until {
  driver.find_element(:id,"uniform-id_gender2").displayed?
}

#Change the state of the Radio Buttons
cb1 = wait.until {
  element1 = driver.find_element(:id,"uniform-id_gender1")
  element1 if element1.displayed?
}
cb1.click if cb1.selected? == false

cb3 = wait.until {
  element2 = driver.find_element(:id,"uniform-id_gender2")
  element2 if element2.displayed?
}
cb3.click if cb3.selected? == false
sleep 4
driver.find_element(:id,"customer_firstname").send_keys "demo"
sleep 3
driver.find_element(:id,"customer_lastname").send_keys "user"
sleep 5
password=driver.find_element(:id,"passwd").send_keys "demo@123"
sleep 4

if driver.find_element(:id,"uniform-days").displayed?
  puts "Days dropdown is displayed.."
  select = driver.find_element(:id,"uniform-days")
  alloptions = select.find_elements(:tag_name,"option")
  puts alloptions.size

  alloptions.each do  |option|
    puts "Value is.."+option.attribute("value")
    if option.attribute("value")=="20"
      option.click
      puts "Value has been selected.."
      sleep 5
      break
    end
  end
end

month_dropdown = driver.find_element(:id,"months")
months=Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(month_dropdown)
months.select_by(:text,"April ")
puts driver.find_element(:id,"months").text.include?("April")

years_dropdown = driver.find_element(:id,"years")
years=Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(years_dropdown)
years.select_by(:index,28)
sleep 3

driver.find_element(:id,"address1").send_keys "45 calony A"
sleep 4

if driver.find_element(:id,"uniform-id_state").displayed?
  puts "State dropdown is displayed.."
  select = driver.find_element(:id,"uniform-id_state")
  alloptions = select.find_elements(:tag_name,"option")
  puts alloptions.size

  alloptions.each do  |option|
    puts "Text is.."+option.attribute("text")
    if option.attribute("text")=="California"
      option.click
      puts "text has been selected.."
      sleep 5
      break
    end
  end
end
#Enter city
driver.find_element(:id,"city").send_keys "Los Angeles"
sleep 4
driver.find_element(:id,"postcode").send_keys "23654"
Country_dropdown =driver.find_element(:id,"id_country")
country=Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(Country_dropdown)
country.select_by(:index,1)
sleep 5

#Input Mobile Number
driver.find_element(:id,"phone_mobile").send_keys "985256238"
sleep 5

#Click on Submit button
driver.find_element(:id,"submitAccount").click
sleep 5
```

I have write script for registration form I have run my automation script then on first time it is successfully pass but when run twice with same email id then it is showing validation message as email already exists try with new one..so for this validation what is the assertion in ruby?

Here is the link for registration form-http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=authentication&back=my-account#account-creation

Comment: Hi,

Can you please update your question so it included what you already tried and a more precise question? Please also read for further guidance on how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. Can you please also add your "script".
Besides that, the link you post seems to be PHP code, not ruby. Can you please also explain this. mIght help us understand more about what you are doing and how we can help you.

Comment: Yes ,I have to automate script in ruby

Comment: Yes ok, can you please add the script, that you have written and gives you this feedback?

We cannot guess how the API/controller is built and also will not completely do the work for you. We are more than happy to help you fix the problems you encounter though.

Comment: I have added script.

Answer (score 1):

**General side notes:**

I see that you have a method defined that you don't use.

```rb
def document_initialised(driver)
  driver.execute_script('return initialised')
end
```

Also there seems to be some un-nneeded variable assignment and not-needed `driver.action.key_down(:enter).perform`

It is possible to create a class to keep your code more structured ;)

**To your question:**

I would create an if to check if the error is displayed on the page or not after you did you submit with `driver.find_element(:id,"SubmitCreate").click`. You can see an example in about it in #register_email in my example.

If I create some class from it and do some other removal of code I think is obsolete, it looks like this (but it has not been tested by me).

```rb
# load in the webdriver gem to interect with selenium
require 'selenium-webdriver'

class RegisterUser
  def run
    return unless register_email
    do_the_rest
  end

  private

  def driver
    return @driver if @driver.present?

    Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path='C:\Users\vidhi\Desktop\Ruby Folder\chromedriver.exe'
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome)
    @driver.get "http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=authentication&back=my-account#account-creation"
    sleep 6
    @driver.manage.window.maximize
    @driver
  end

  def wait 
    Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 20)
  end

  def register_email
    driver.find_element(:id,"email_create").send_keys "demouser099@gmail.com"
    driver.find_element(:id,"SubmitCreate").click
    sleep 5

    return true unless driver.find_element(:id,"create_account_error").displayed?

    # An account using this email address has already been registered. 
    # Please enter a valid password or request a new one.
    puts driver.find_element(:id,"create_account_error").text
    false
  end

  def do_the_rest
    # Here you can put the rest of the code, or clean up even more and split into multiple methods
  end
end

RegisterUser.new.run
```